# .hover() doesnt work with touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click the elemnt (mobile) with the id, the class is displayed but removed at the same moment. The class 'animate' which is to display a div is only visible for a short time.

The code works perfectly in Chrome and does what it should.

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve the problem?

```
( function($) {

$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#apache-table-mod').hover(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('animate');
        });


    });
} ) ( jQuery );
```

Comment: how does one hover with a touch screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery hover menu not working for touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476264/jquery-hover-menu-not-working-for-touch)

Comment: On touch devices if you need hover effect you can count how menu times user click (touch) on the link. You can make that first touch to be hover and second touch to be real link click

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Actually you [can do that..](https://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/technologies/floating-touch/) it's normally a gimmick and turned off due to it draining the battery though.

Answer (score 5):

You can't hover on mobile. Instead, you could detect the click on your element and use jquery animate() to start your animation